# laravel url admin voyager

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I have multi language site on laravel. I used admin panel voyager. I do not understand the url admin and multilingualism.
I have route this multilanguage

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'GeneralController@index')->name('general.show');
});
```

and I have url for the admin panel voayager

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();
});
```

but I can not enter the voyager admin panel. It just displays the main page. Please advise me how to add these two codes. Thanks in advance with cookies.

Comment: Try to put route group with prefix admin - above of all other routes/groups.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try this

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}/admin'], function () {
Voyager::routes();
});
```

Comment: @raksh outputs 404

Comment: run this cmd  php artisan optimize  and then    php artisan route:list  and check your routes